# How to import Activity of NfcFCardEmulation.EnableService from Xamarin common project, not Android project?

Tags: xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android, hce

I'm developing an app using Xamarin's HCE feature.
The project structure is as follows.
hceSample
hceSample.Android
hceSample.iOS

I am implementing hce simulation code called hceService in hceSample, not hceSample.Android.
A function called Enable_Card exists in the hce service, and you want to use the NfcFCardEmulation.EnableService function in that function.
Activity and ComponentName are requested as parameters of the function.
The ComponentName area was handled easily, but I don't know how to get the Activity. Please advise.

This is the contents of enable_Card function of hceService.

```
private Activity activity = null;
private bool enable_Card(cardModel card)
        {
            try
            {
                sid = card.cardSN;
                tag = "Felica";
                emulation.EnableService(, componentName); //<- How to get Activity??
                emulation.SetNfcid2ForService(componentName, sid);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow.
I would appreciate it if you could point out any missing or incorrect parts.

I trying this

1. activity = Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity; //<- this function is not found!

Added missing information!
The namespace of the Enable_Card function is located in hceSample.Service.

Comment: Do you have Xamarin Essentials in your Project?

Comment: Yes, My project using Xamarin.Essentials! As far as I know, getting Activity values ​​using Xamarin Essentials is only possible in Android projects.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Why do you need a reference for it in your Shared project though?

Comment: We recognize that hardware service is the right and ideal way to implement in each OS project. However, I'm curious if there is a way to code Android and iOS at the same time, so I'm researching.

Comment: there isn't you need to have native separate code for both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [NfcFCardEmulation.EnableService(Activity, ComponentName) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.nfc.cardemulators.nfcfcardemulation.enableservice?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12), right?

The method is an android `api` from android sdk,you cannot use it `directly` in xamarin.form(yours is `hceSample`) project.

If you want to call the function in xamarin form project(`hceSample`) from native platform(`hceSample.Android`, or `hceSample.iOS`),you can use [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve this.

The `DependencyService` class is a service locator that enables `Xamarin.Forms` applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code.

For more information about `DependencyService`, you can check document [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction). And there is a sample included in above document,which is helpful for you to understand `DependencyService`.

**Note:**

> We recognize that hardware service is the right and ideal way to
> implement in each OS project. However, I'm curious if there is a way
> to code Android and iOS at the same time

Since the api you used is from android sdk, you can call it in native android or use `DependencyService` to call it on xamarin.form(yours is `hceSample`) project.

If you call it on xamarin.form(yours is `hceSample`) project, you also need to find the the corresponding function or interface in iOS.